# Does time remaining matter in NO Touch-ONE Touch probabilities?

Tags: options, quant-trading-strategies, probability

I asked a question some days back and got an answer which I understand and make sense:
[Probability of touching short call strike and not touching touching short put strike of a short strangle?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/65449/probability-of-touching-short-call-strike-and-not-touching-touching-short-put-st/65453#65453)

However, the answer to that question brought up another related question to my mind.

With the probability of that event happening given as **P(A ∩ Bcomplement)=P(A)−P(A∩B)**:

Is that the probability for the event **with or without time still left to expiration**?

Or the probability of the event **only without time left in the trade**?

**NOTE: Because if there is still time in the trade, it can still touch B before the trade expires even though it touched A first and satisfied the condition**

Answer (score 1):

Referring to one touch down no touch up (OTD-NTU) option with expiry $T$ as interpreted in your [previous question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/65490/one-touch-up-no-touch-down-one-touch-down-no-touch-up), it might help to formalize the payoff stated in the respective [answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/65497/6858).

The option pays rebate \$1 *at expiry* $T$ if

$$  \boxed{ \tau_L \leq T \; {\rm and} \; \tau_L < \tau^H }$$  where:

$$ \tau_L = \min  \; \{t \geq 0 : S_t \leq L  \} $$

and

$$ \tau^H = \min \; \{t \geq 0 : S_t \geq  H  \}, $$

with $L< S_0 < H$.

Its price amounts to calculating (under $Q$ probability measure)

$$ E^Q\left[e^{-rT}1_{\{\tau_L \leq T\} \cap \{\tau_L < \tau^H\}}\right]=e^{-rT} Q(\{\tau_L \leq T\} \cap \{\tau_L < \tau^H\}), $$

where $1_A$ is $1$ if event $A$ takes place, and $0$ otherwise, and $r$ is a flat risk-free discount rate.

The \$1 rebate pay can be made *at touching (hitting) time* $\tau_L$ too, in which case the price of the option is:

$$  E^Q\left[e^{-r\tau_L} 1_{\{\tau_L \leq T\} \cap \{\tau_L < 
 \tau^H\}}\right]. $$

Its calculation is more complex (pay timing is random).

Back to your $A$ and $B$ events in the question, they are:

$$ A = \{\tau_L \leq T  \}, \; B = \{\tau^H \leq T  \}.$$

So, the *payoff* for which

$$Q(A\cap B^c) = Q(\{\tau_L \leq T\} \cap \{\tau^H  > T\})$$

would be its *price* is the one that would pay \$1 at expiry $T$ if

$$ \boxed{ \tau_L \leq T \; {\rm and} \; \tau^H > T.} $$

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it is a bit math-heavy for me but in summary you mean it would payoff only at the expiration?

Comment: For the last boxed payoff yes.

Comment: In general, no. For a NTD (no touch down) option there is only one pay date possible, expiry (or after expiry). For one touch down (OTD) option the pay date can be the hitting time ($\tau$) itself, that is, pay date is random. Same for  OTD-NTU (in which case the option terminates immediately with 0 pay when the $H$ gets hit before $L$ does). This forces us to think in terms of the hitting time itself (its expectation, distribution, joint distribution with other hitting times  etc.), not just POT probabilities of events like $\tau_L \leq T$ where $T$ is fixed, $Q(\tau \leq T)$.

Comment: (Note that last probability can be seen as $Q(\tau_L \leq T)=Q(\min_{t\leq T} S_t < L)$, the probability of the  minimum of stock price over the life of the option being less than $L$)